# Saving document to WSS gives script error

Tags: sharepoint, wss, document-library

I have a custom content type with two extra columns defined in WSS 3.0. I have a document list with word documents of that content type.

When I open a document on my XP client with MS Office 2003 and IE6 (company regulations :-( ) this works fine. When I make changes however and I try to save the document, I get following error:

[image]

I don't know what is causing this: IE6, Word 2003, WSS 3.0 ... Does anyone have an idea?

Thanks,
Jelle

Comment: IE6??? Shouldn't you address that problem first? It is insecure as hell and as of SP2010 an unsupported browser...

Comment: I know. But that is something I cannot control. The company that I currently work for still uses IE6 as only supported browser. They will keep on doing that until, and I am not kidding, July 2011. I would like to solve my problem without starting a discussion with the CTO; a discussion that I cannot win.

Comment: I've seen the problem before. We had the problem with the property pane (or whatever it is called,the little pop-up with metadata from SharePoint you see when you save a document in Office 2003). Apparently the columns were screwed up a bit, specifically the internal names were incorrect, this happened after saving site as template and using a site based on that template

Comment: How did you solve it? Did you have to create the entire site again or was there an easy solution?